# Planned Restful JSON apis for Healthcare Finder?

Tags: json, healthcare-finder-api

Are there any plans to provide a restful / json version of these apis?

I realize that some of the urls contain the WORD rest (e.g. https://hiosgateway.cms.gov/RBIS-API/v11.0/REST/getSBCReportFile?planId=59830MI0010009&fileType=pdf) but that shows a fundamental misunderstanding of what REST is.

A restful approach would be something like http://hiosgateway.cms.org/RBIS-API/v11.0/rest/plan/59830MI0010009/brochure.

The issue of calling RPC REST aside - json is significantly easier to consume and provide considering the overwrought complexity of the competing healthcare.gov xml schemas. Any chance this is on the roadmap?